# How do I repartition a hard drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I bought a laptop with a 500GB HDD.  It came with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.  The drive was partitioned into one 452GB partition (C:) and a recovery partition.

I decided to divide the C Drive. The size of C drive is 411 GB (452-41) where 41 GB space is utilized by the OS and other pre-loaded software.

My goal is the following partitions:

1. 100GB
2. 100GB
3. 100GB
4. C: of 111GB

I did steps 1 & 2 successfully with Windows 7's built-in partition tool (the one which opens from control panel).  After that the tool shows only 14GB as a third partition instead of 100 GB as i wished in step 3.  C: drive is 211GB.

Why did this happen?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you say the size of C is 411GB? I know you've used 41GB for the OS, but the size doesn't change, just the free space. What size is C after you've done all this partitioning? C should be 152GB to be consistent with the overall 452GB

Comment: the size of c drive after all partitioning done by me is 211 GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click My Computer and click Manage. On the left side expand the Storage category and go to Disk Management. There you will see all the disks connected to your computer. There will probably be a portion of Disk 0 (depending on your configuration) that has a black bar above it indicating unallocated space. Right-click this and click Format.

Note:
From here you can also right-click any other partitions and shrink, extend, delete, or assign drive letters to them.

Comment: @paolo: thanks but the steps you have written is what i have followed but i was not able to partition drive as discussed in my question

Comment: downvoted because these instructions do not detail *repartitioning* the drive, as the poster requested.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look with [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). Very effective, fairly simple to use and I've known it to find partitions and act on them that Windows couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Like outsideblasts said you can use GParted to change the partitions and it works great. However, before you destroy your recovery partition make sure you follow all steps from the manufacturer to create your recovery disks.

Comment: i tried gpart, but create parition was disabled. it showed that my HDD is dynamic drive. Why so?